# headphones not working but external speakers working

Tags: sound, headphones

I'm running ubuntu 13.10, and my headphones have randomly stopped working - sound plays from the laptop speakers when the headphones are unplugged, but no sound comes through the headphones. The headphones themselves work, and are detected by the computer. I'm not sure what could be wrong, please help?

Comment: have you tried manually selecting the headphones output in the sound setting??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that - when they are plugged in the computer says that it is using the headphones output. Does this mean it's a problem with the jack?

Comment: If you're sure that the headphones work, then it sounds like a hardware problem with the jack.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Do you know whether such a problem is easily/cheaply repairable?

Comment: I think I have a similar problem. They stopped working after I successively opened Clementine and Audacity. I now only hear little "breathing" or crackle every time a sound is supposed to be sent to them. The system detects them fine because it switches automatically to the right output and mutes the laptop speakers until the headphones are unplugged again. The sound level is also remembered.
I also was afraid of a hardware issue, but I figured that it wasn't one after creating a 13.10 usb startup disk and booting onto it and testing the headphones - they work fine!
Any developments for you?